# How to make both top and bottom space same using matrix

Tags: matrices

I tried with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%amssymb,
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

Outputs to machine learning models are also often represented as vectors. For instance, consider an object recognition model that takes an image as input and emits a set of numbers indicating the probabilities that the image contains a  dog, human, or cat, respectively.  The output of such a model is a three element vector $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix}y_{0}\\y_{1}\\y_{2}\\\dfrac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$, where the number $y_{0}$ denotes the probability that the image contains a dog, $y_{1}$ denotes the~probability that the image contains a human, and $y_{2}$ denotes the probability that the image contains a cat. Figure~\ref{fig:vec_out} shows some possible input images and corresponding output vectors.
\begin{align*}
p\left( x \right)
&= \overbrace{ \pi_{1}}^{0.33}\mathcal{N}\left( \vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{1} }^{\begin{bmatrix}
152\\55
\end{bmatrix}} \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{1}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
20 &0\\0 &28
\end{bmatrix} } \right)
+ \overbrace{ \pi_{2} }^{0.33} \mathcal{N}\left(\vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{2}  }^{  \begin{bmatrix}
175\\70
\end{bmatrix}  }, \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{2}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 39\\39 & 51
\end{bmatrix} } \right)\\
&+ \overbrace{ \pi_{3} }^{0.33} \mathcal{N}\left(\vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{3} }^{  \begin{bmatrix}
135\\40
\end{bmatrix} }, \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{3}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
10 & 0\\0 & 10
\end{bmatrix} } \right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Output produced as:

[image]

How can I make equal space at top and bottom of the matrix? Please advise

Also, it's more helpful that if any one explain why this was happend.

Comment: Can you please add a sketch of the expected output?

Comment: @egreg Updated image uploaded, please let me know, if this is clear

Comment: Off-topic: Is `\dfrac{1}{2}` in the definition of `\vec{y}` out of place?

Comment: Thanks to `egreg`, `Mico` and `Sandy G`, may I know, why this was happening? I'm curious to know, how.

Comment: @GowriSaro - Sorry, but how would anybody but you know how the `\dfrac{1}{2}` instruction got inserted in *your* code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could enclose the contents of each portion with `\vcenter{\hbox{$ ... $}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%amssymb,
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
p\left( x \right)
&= \overbrace{ \pi_{1}}^{0.33}\mathcal{N}\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$ \vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{1} }^{\begin{bmatrix}
152\\55
\end{bmatrix}} \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{1}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
20 &0\\0 &28
\end{bmatrix} } $}}\right)
+ \overbrace{ \pi_{2} }^{0.33} \mathcal{N}\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$ \vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{2}  }^{  \begin{bmatrix}
175\\70
\end{bmatrix}  }, \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{2}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 39\\39 & 51
\end{bmatrix} } $}}\right)\\
&+ \overbrace{ \pi_{3} }^{0.33} \mathcal{N}\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$ \vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{3} }^{  \begin{bmatrix}
135\\40
\end{bmatrix} }, \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{3}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
10 & 0\\0 & 10
\end{bmatrix} } $}}\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{gathered}...\end{gathered}` instead of `\vcenter{\hbox{$...$}}` seems more LaTeX-savvy. And anyway, it's not like the OP seems to want, because the vectors are misaligned.

Answer (score 6):

You have received a nice answer, but I warmly suggest to get away with `\overbrace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

Outputs to machine learning models are also often represented as vectors. 
For instance, consider an object recognition model that takes an image as 
input and emits a set of numbers indicating the probabilities that the 
image contains a  dog, human, or cat, respectively.  The output of such 
a model is a three element vector
$\vec{y} = [\begin{matrix}y_{0} & y_{1} & y_{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{matrix}]^T$, 
where the number $y_{0}$ denotes the probability that the image contains a dog, 
$y_{1}$ denotes the~probability that the image contains a human, and $y_{2}$ 
denotes the probability that the image contains a cat. Figure~\ref{fig:vec_out} 
shows some possible input images and corresponding output vectors.
\begin{gather*}
p(x) = \pi_{1} \mathcal{N} ( \vec{x}; \, \vec{\mu}_{1}, \bm{\Sigma}_{1})
     + \pi_{2} \mathcal{N} ( \vec{x}; \, \vec{\mu}_{2}, \bm{\Sigma}_{2})
     + \pi_{3} \mathcal{N} ( \vec{x}; \, \vec{\mu}_{3}, \bm{\Sigma}_{3})
\\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
\pi_1&=0.33 & \pi_2&=0.33 & \pi_3&=0.33
\\
\vec{\mu}_{1}&=\begin{bmatrix} 152 \\ 55 \end{bmatrix}, &
\vec{\mu}_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix} 175 \\ 70 \end{bmatrix}, &
\vec{\mu}_{3}&=\begin{bmatrix} 135 \\ 40 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\bm{\Sigma}_{1}&=\begin{bmatrix} 20 &  0 \\  0 & 28 \end{bmatrix}, &
\bm{\Sigma}_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix} 35 & 39 \\ 39 & 51 \end{bmatrix}, &
\bm{\Sigma}_{3}&=\begin{bmatrix} 10 &  0 \\  0 & 10 \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Note the column vector written as the transpose of a row vector, which avoids gaps between lines.

[image]

With an alternative alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

Outputs to machine learning models are also often represented as vectors. 
For instance, consider an object recognition model that takes an image as 
input and emits a set of numbers indicating the probabilities that the 
image contains a  dog, human, or cat, respectively.  The output of such 
a model is a three element vector
$\vec{y} = [\begin{matrix}y_{0} & y_{1} & y_{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{matrix}]^T$, 
where the number $y_{0}$ denotes the probability that the image contains a dog, 
$y_{1}$ denotes the~probability that the image contains a human, and $y_{2}$ 
denotes the probability that the image contains a cat. Figure~\ref{fig:vec_out} 
shows some possible input images and corresponding output vectors.
\begin{alignat*}{3}
p(x) = \pi_{1} &\mathcal{N} ( \vec{x}; \, \vec{\mu}_{1}, \bm{\Sigma}_{1})
     &{}+ \pi_{2} &\mathcal{N} ( \vec{x}; \, \vec{\mu}_{2}, \bm{\Sigma}_{2})
     &{}+ \pi_{3} &\mathcal{N} ( \vec{x}; \, \vec{\mu}_{3}, \bm{\Sigma}_{3})
\\[1ex]
\pi_1&=0.33 & \pi_2&=0.33 & \pi_3&=0.33
\\
\vec{\mu}_{1}&=\begin{bmatrix} 152 \\ 55 \end{bmatrix}, &
\vec{\mu}_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix} 175 \\ 70 \end{bmatrix}, &
\vec{\mu}_{3}&=\begin{bmatrix} 135 \\ 40 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\bm{\Sigma}_{1}&=\begin{bmatrix} 20 &  0 \\  0 & 28 \end{bmatrix}, &
\bm{\Sigma}_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix} 35 & 39 \\ 39 & 51 \end{bmatrix}, &
\bm{\Sigma}_{3}&=\begin{bmatrix} 10 &  0 \\  0 & 10 \end{bmatrix}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, here's how you can do the proposed task. I left the big inline column vector in order to show why it's really bad.

Comparing the outputs I have no doubt whatsoever.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

Outputs to machine learning models are also often represented as vectors. 
For instance, consider an object recognition model that takes an image as 
input and emits a set of numbers indicating the probabilities that the 
image contains a  dog, human, or cat, respectively.  The output of such 
a model is a three element vector
$\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix}y_{0} \\ y_{1} \\ y_{2} \\ \dfrac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$, 
where the number $y_{0}$ denotes the probability that the image contains a dog, 
$y_{1}$ denotes the~probability that the image contains a human, and $y_{2}$ 
denotes the probability that the image contains a cat. Figure~\ref{fig:vec_out} 
shows some possible input images and corresponding output vectors.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
p(x)
&= \overbrace{ \pi_{1}}^{0.33}\mathcal{N}
\begin{array}[b]({c})
\vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{1} }^{\begin{bmatrix}
152\\55
\end{bmatrix}} \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{1}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
20 &0\\0 &28
\end{bmatrix} }
\end{array}
+ \overbrace{ \pi_{2} }^{0.33} \mathcal{N}
\begin{array}[b]({c})
\vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{2}  }^{  \begin{bmatrix}
175\\70
\end{bmatrix}  }, \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{2}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
35 & 39\\39 & 51
\end{bmatrix} }
\end{array}\\
&+ \overbrace{ \pi_{3} }^{0.33} \mathcal{N}
\begin{array}[b]({c})\vec{x}; \, \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{3} }^{  \begin{bmatrix}
135\\40
\end{bmatrix} }, \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{3}}^{ \begin{bmatrix}
10 & 0\\0 & 10
\end{bmatrix} }
\end{array}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion is fantastic, but the Prof. doesn't want to rephrase his original derivation

Comment: @GowriSaro I added a simple way to obtain the (preposterously bad) output your Prof seems to like.

Comment: My sincere apologies :-(

Answer (score 5):

It suffices to replace the three instances of `\left( ... \right)` with `\bigl( ... \bigr)`. Observe that since the second arguments of the larger `\overbrace` constructs are explanatory rather than definitional, they need not be encased in the (now no longer very tall) parentheses.

Oh, and unless you want to draw lots of attention to the definition of `\vec{y}` in the paragraph that precedes the `align*` environment, I'd write it as a row vector rather than as a column vector.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\begin{document}

Outputs to machine learning models are also often represented as vectors. For instance, consider an object recognition model that takes an image as input and emits a set of numbers indicating the probabilities that the image contains a  dog, human, or cat, respectively.  The output of such a model is a three element vector
$\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_{0} & y_{1} & y_{2} \end{bmatrix}'$, 
where the number $y_{0}$ denotes the probability that the image contains a dog, $y_{1}$ denotes the~probability that the image contains a human, and $y_{2}$ denotes the probability that the image contains a cat. Figure~\ref{fig:vec_out} shows some possible input images and corresponding output vectors.
\begin{align*}
p(x)
&=\overbrace{ \pi_{1}\mathstrut}^{0.33}\mathcal{N}
  \bigl( \vec{x};  
  \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{1} }^{
      \begin{bmatrix} 152\\55 \end{bmatrix}} ,
  \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{1}}^{ 
      \begin{bmatrix} 20 &0\\0 &28 \end{bmatrix} } 
  \bigr)
 +\overbrace{ \pi_{2}\mathstrut}^{0.33} \mathcal{N}
  \bigl(\vec{x};  
  \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{2}  }^{  
      \begin{bmatrix} 175\\70 \end{bmatrix}  }, 
  \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{2}}^{ 
      \begin{bmatrix} 35 & 39\\39 & 51 \end{bmatrix} } 
  \bigr) 
  \\[2\jot] % insert a bit more vertical whitespace
&\quad+\overbrace{ \pi_{3}\mathstrut}^{0.33} \mathcal{N}
 \bigl(\vec{x};  
 \overbrace{ \vec{\mu}_{3} }^{  
     \begin{bmatrix} 135\\40 \end{bmatrix} }, 
 \overbrace{ \bm{\Sigma}_{3}}^{ 
     \begin{bmatrix} 10 & 0\\0 & 10 \end{bmatrix} } 
 \bigr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is fantastic, but the Prof. doesn't want to rephrase his original derivation

Comment: @GowriSaro - Thanks. I wish you all the best for developing a good sense of typographic style that can see through -- and, hopefully, will have the opportunity to simply ignore -- the inadequacies of individual faculty's approaches to typesetting, and math typesetting in particular.

Comment: My sincere apologies :-(

Comment: @GowriSaro - Hey, no need for *you* to apologize! Just draw the right conclusions, not only for the specific typesetting issue but also for some general typesetting matters, from the experience of your query and the answers you received.